# 8-bit Serial I/O Parallel I/O Bi-Directional Shift Register

Tags: serial, parallel, shift-register, register, bidirectional

I am looking for a register that has as stated Serial In Parallel Out and Parallel In Serial Out modes and bi-directional shift functionality all in one IC. I want to use it with Arduino. Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. The 74HC/HCT194 is, as far as I can tell, exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you tell me the 8-bit version of this thing.

Comment: That would be the 74198. Of course, it doesn't come in CMOS. The 74HC323 is also a candidate, but its inputs and outputs are common, so interfacing to it is a bit more complicated.